# Select2 Copy values from one select2 to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a global select2 control, and when a button is clicked I would like to take the selected values and populate various other select2 controls with them.

How do I add replicate the selected values from one select2 control to another?

I have tried the following:

```
//Set Up control where values will copy to
$(hashElement).select2({
            multiple: true,
            data: Details,
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                data = $.parseJSON(element.val());
                callback(data);
            }
        });


var ApplyGlobalValues = function () {
        // get hashtag values 
        var values = $("#SelectGlobal").select2("val");
        $(".select-children").select2('val', values).trigger("change");
    }
```

The button fires ApplyGlobalValues() and initSelection is hit, but the values don't populate. What am i Doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I created an example that copies the values of a select2 to another select2. The first trick is, when you use the initSelection, you must set a default value attribute on the html input element. The second trick is, you must get the 'data' property of the select2 element instead of the 'val' property to get the values as an object array.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="select2example1" type="hidden" value="1,1,2">
<input id="select2example2" type="hidden" value="1,1,2">
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="copy to other select2">
```

**JS:**

```
var data = [{
        id: 1,
        text: "A"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "B"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        text: "C"
    }];


    $("#select2example1").select2({
        multiple: true,
        data: data,
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = [{ id: 1, text: 'A' }, { id: 3, text: 'C' }];
            callback(data);
        }
    });

    $("#select2example1").select2('val', '1,2');

    var ApplyGlobalValues = function () {

        var values = $("#select2example1").select2("data");
        $('#select2example2').select2({
            multiple: true,
            data: data,
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var data = values;
                callback(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $("#mybutton").click(function () {
        ApplyGlobalValues();
    });
```

See also:
http://jsfiddle.net/08us1mg5/

Comment: Thanks, I did get this sorted but dint answer because there were not many views